# To delete a file, located in the search path, in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filepath

I have a file located in `/path/to/Matlab/myData.mat`. The path `/path/to/Matlab` has been in the search path. I launch Matlab from `/path/to/Matlab/workspace/`.

However, the command `if (exist('myData.mat','file')==2) delete('myData.mat');` returns error saying that `File myData.mat cannot be found`.

There is only one file named `myData.mat` among all the search paths. Is it mandatory to use absolute or relative path when call the `delete()` function providing the location has been added to the search path?

My OS is Ubuntu 16, and Matlab v2015b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which` to find the full path